# Hiding file in address bar

Tags: url-rewriting

I've created a PHP pagination system, but I want to hide the _GET variable in the address bar.

At the moment mine looks like this: `http://example.com/images.php?page=1`

But I've seen a few site that have `http://example.com/images/1/`.

Just wondering how they go about this? Can anyone point me in the right direction? Cheers

Comment: Your accept ratio is very low, I suggest you to accept some more answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need support from your web server to get the requests right and rewrite the requests of `/images/1/` internally to `/images.php?page=1`. Most web server have a module or extension to support such behavior like [Apache’s mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html), [lighttpd’s mod_rewrite](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs:ModRewrite), [ISAPI Rewrite module for ISS](http://www.isapirewrite.com/), etc.

Comment: thanks, knew it could be done, i just didn't know what to search for to get me started.

Comment: @micheal: This technique is called URL/URI rewriting.

Answer (score 1):

That's called `PATH_INFO`

The server must support it and enable it.

If it does, then you may access it using `$_SERVER["PATH_INFO"]`

Comment: That isn't what PHP_INFO is... this is called mod_rewriting.

Comment: Delete this answer otherwise you'll regret it.

Comment: +1 `PATH_INFO` is a perfectly valid way of rewriting URLs without the help of mod_rewrite with the limitation that the URL will have to contain the PHP file name: `www.example.com/images.php/1/` .

Comment: @zaf: I'll regret what, rotfl? I misspelled `PHP_INFO` instead of `PATH_INFO`. Using `PATH_INFO` works and does *exactly* what he wants.

Comment: @Lo'oris Ah you've edited your answer! Still, it won't work because if you look at the question closely you'll note that its '/images/' not '/images.php/' meaning that PATH_INFO won't have a chance since the webserver has already done a 404.

Comment: Yes, as Pekka pointed out it requires you to write the extension too, so if it's really a requirement not to do it, then this is not an option. Still, this might have sufficed for him. I don't understand what you mean about the 404.

Answer (score 0):

Most frameworks take care of it, but you need to configure your web server to handle it.  Here are instructions [from CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite/) on setting up apache htacces.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using apache then you can use mod_rewrite to do this kind of magic: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine

Answer (score 0):

If your server is Apache, you can create a file called .htaccess (it has no filename, only an extension - it's worth giving it a name on your local machine because some file systems hide files with no name) and learn how to use [RewriteRules](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

It's very easy to use for simple rewrites like you want.

A sample .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

#Translate http://address.com/images/1/ to http://address.com/images.php?page=1
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ / images.php5?page=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually all requests are redirected (their URL is internally rewrited) to single PHP script using Apache [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) and `RewriteEngine`, then (in that script) the URL is examined and handler matching this URL (if there are more handlers) with corresponding arguments is called. Some frameworks in PHP, usually [MVC ones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller#PHP), are entirely built on one single *index.php* to which all requests are "redirected" (URL-rewrited).

If you need just to solve the problem with `?page=`, try rewriting URL `/images/1/` to `/images.php?page=1` (as Gumbo suggests) with this in Apache configuration (the *.htaccess* file for example):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^images/([0-9]+)/?$ images.php?page=$1 [L]
```